# PHP mail() goes to junk, possible DNS issue?

Tags: php, email, dns, spam

I am sending a message via PHP's mail() with proper and complete headers. It has everything it is supposed to, and Hotmail likes the email itself.
However, Hotmail is showing this in the source of the message:

```
X-DKIM-Result: None
X-Message-Status: n:0:n
X-SID-Result: None
X-AUTH-Result: NONE
```

I tried to get them to Pass but only managed to turn the SID and AUTH to "Fail" causing SmartScreen to see the message as suspicious and delete it after ten days, whereas before it just seemed like spam to the filters.

If I am able to get these to Pass, then the email will not be marked as junk. I know there's something I need to do in DNS. I have Reverse DNS set up on the website.

The email includes boundaries, MIME version, content type, reply-to and return-path, x-mailer etc. The content type is multipart/alternative (for the boundaries) and the subject nor body does not contain any spammy keywords.

Anyone know how to get these things to Pass via PHP or DNS?

**Bottom line:** If these results are "None" then it will just go to Junk peacefully. If they are "Fail" then it will be "suspicious" and automatically deleted. If they are "Pass" then it will go straight to inbox without a problem, but I don't know how to get them to Pass.

If it helps in any way, I am running Exim 4.77 on a cPanel/WHM (Linux) VPS. My IP address is clean and hasn't been abused in the past. It isn't blocked at any blacklists.

Comment: If your reverse DNS matches your hostname that's pretty much all you can do for sending e-mails properly to my knowledge. Everything else might be because your content looks too much like spam.

Comment: how about you try to send it using smtp authentication using an actual mail user account.  also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437611/hotmail-treating-my-emails-as-junk

Comment: also it is good idea to make sure that your server ip is not blacklisted.

Comment: Turns out I am blacklisted with Sorbs. Just got this IP. Turns out it was used for Spam in Jun 2011 and the blacklist states that it will cause me email problems. I'm going to get my data center to remove that one, it's very hard to get off. I'll update tomorrow with the news.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup the [SPF record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) in your DNS, can be a solution.

EDIT

Googling the message  **X-AUTH-Result: FAIL**  I found this post, that seem the same problem:
https://serverfault.com/questions/138886/emails-going-to-junk-for-hotmail-recipients

Comment: Whenever I make an SPF record, then it goes to Fail for some reason.

Comment: @Bailey: can you be more specific about the reason?

Comment: I do not know of a reason. The following change to Fail (they were None) when I add SPF to my domain: X-SID-Result: Fail
X-AUTH-Result: FAIL

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the server the mail is being sent from has a proper rDNS or PTR record back to it's hostname.